# How would I constrain the button and the image?

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints

I've been trying to constrain this image and button:

[image]

But, I have not been able to get it quite right. How would I constrain it to make it look like the image above on all screens?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following constraints for the image

[image: Imagw 1]

and the following constraints for the button

[image]

(You create a "Proportional Width" constraint by first creating an "Equal width" constraint and then changing the multiplier. If you want the button to be half the width of the superview, set the multiplier to 0.5)

You can set the alignment of the button to left: (In the identity inspector)

[image]

Comment: Your solution works, but it only works if the button text is short enough.

Comment: Ok. How would you like the button to react when the text is too long? Move icon to left? Shrink font? Text in multiple lines?

Comment: The button text will stay the same.

Comment: Ok. How would you like the button to react when the text is too long? Move icon to left? Shrink font? Text in multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply put these views into horizontal `StackView`. The main thing is to set alignment to `center`.

Example using `UIKitPlus` library

```swift
HStack {
    Image(...)
    Button(...)
}
.alignment(.center)
.spacing(8)
```